# Excel: merge two date columns that dont quite match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 4 columns 2 with dates and 2 with counts.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro7m9.png

[image]

I want to merge the two date columns and show the 2 count columns but only with if the second count has data for that date put it in.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS3QZ.png

[image]

I am using Excel 2016
Any help would be appreciated.

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dle0vn3uf6xzd4/sample.xlsx?dl=0`

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you run into a problem.  It would seem this could be done using simple lookup formula.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks. I would love to have this automated if possible.
I will be adding data to the sheet and extracting it all the time and running lookups every 15 mins is not feasible.

Comment: You can achieve that with a simple `VLookup` formula.

Comment: @michaelosmith For more automation, make the data ranges into Tables.  That way the references and lookup formulas will just extend as you add data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For situations like this, [VLookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) is very helpful.

In column C2, type the following:

```
= VLookup(A2, $D:$E, 2, false)
```

Then fill column C2 down to the bottom.

This will populate column C with any matching value from E.  When there is no match, the cell will display `#N/A`.

You can now sum cells from column B with cells from column C using a normal formula.  The errors may get in the way, but you can eliminate them with another formula.

In cell F2, type

```
= B2 + If(IsError(C2),0,C2)
```

... and fill down once again.

Column F now contains the totals.

Answer (score 0):

Dim result As String 
Dim sheet As Worksheet 
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1") 
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sheet.Range("A:A"), sheet.Range("D1:E30"), 2, False)